# Parsing and Syntax directed translation

Tags: parsing

Consider the following grammar (that admits a series of declarations, followed by expressions) and the associated syntax directed translation (SDT) actions, given as pseudo-code

```
P -> D*E*
D -> int ID{record that ID.lexeme is of type int}
D -> bool ID{record that ID.lexeme is of type bool}
E -> El + E2 {check that E1.type = E2.type = int; set E.type := int}
E -> !E1 {check that E1.type = bool; set E.type := bool}
E -> ID {set E.type := int}
```

With respect to the above grammar, which one of the following choices is correct?

A . The actions can be used to correctly type-check any syntactically correct program

B . The actions can be used to type-check syntactically correct integer variable declarations and
integer expressions

C . The actions can be used to type-check syntactically correct boolean variable declarations and
boolean expressions.

D . The actions will lead to an infinite loop

[I am confused in option B and C, as both integer and boolean are being checked in pseudo code. please anyone can guide me which point I have forgotten to take into consideration ]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. This would be a good moment to [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and specifically the [help page on how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As it says there, we discourage questions which include important information in the form of an image. Textual information should be copied or typed directly into your question, so that other people can easily read it (images are often hard to read), quote it in an answer, or find it in a search. You can edit your quesiton using the `Edit` button just below the tags. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try working through that grammar and its actions with the following short input, which is syntactically valid and correctly typed:

```
bool A
!A
```

The problem is that the action for `E → ID` unconditionally sets the type of the expression to `int`; since `A` has been declared to be `bool`, `!A` is a valid expression but it will fail the type check in `E → E1`.

So neither answer A nor C can apply.